# Which partition size for fresh install Debian Wheezy with 6 Disk in Raid?

Tags: installation, raid6

i want to install Wheezy on a System with 6x3TB Disk. The aim is to use the most of it for a samba share. My idea is to make:
1 partition on each disk for gpt with 100MB
1 partition for "/" with 3GB on each Disk in Raid1, which makes 9GB at all
1 partition for SWAP in Raid6 with 2GB on each Disk, which makes 8GB at all
and finaly the Rest in new Mountpoint with Raid6, nearly 11TB

The server has 8GB RAM. Should i use this configuration or better another raid for "/" and SWAP? All partitions will formated with ext4.

thx

Answer (score 0):

I'd just make one big R6 array and use LVM to carve it up as you like - it won't make any significant difference from a performance perspective but will be fully protected and very flexible. Oh and it you have such a large array why not give root the other non-shared FS's a bit more space, you can afford it.

Comment: Thx, but i dont want another layer between. if there is any trouble i have to analyse lvm too. but your right it listen good. my main question behind is the kind of raid to use. should i use raid1 for swap or better raid 6 e.g.